# RxSwift - how to have readable combineLatest event element variable names?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

```
var isCurrentlySearchingAddress = Variable<Bool>(false)
var currentSelectedPlace = Variable<GeocodePlace?>(nil)
```

when I make a subscription on

```
Observable.combineLatest(viewModel.isCurrentlySearchingAddress.asObservable(), viewModel.currentSelectedPlace.asObservable())
```

How can I have readable variable names instead of `0` and `1`?

[image]

Comment: You're force unwrapping `element` here, what if it throws an error?

Comment: Better to use `onNext`, if you dont want to handle error

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in `next` events you can do this:

```
Observable.combineLatest(isCurrentlySearchingAddress.asObservable(), currentSelectedPlace.asObservable())
   .subscribe(onNext: { (isSearchingAddress, selectedPlace) in

   })
```

Or this (if you want to keep using `subscribe`):

```
Observable.combineLatest(isCurrentlySearchingAddress.asObservable(), currentSelectedPlace.asObservable())
   .subscribe { event in
      if case let .next(isSearchingAddress, selectedPlace) = event {

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    Observable.combineLatest(
        varA.asObservable(), varB.asObservable(),
        resultSelector: { value1, value2 in
            print("\(value1) \(value2)")
    }).observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you're using the `subscribe(on:)` then force unwrapping `element`. In case of error the `element` will we `nil` and it will cause crash. It is not a good idea to force unwrap it.

If you're sure that the sequence will never emit error or you don't want to handle the error then it's better to use `subscribe(onNext:)` like this:

```
Observable.combineLatest(viewModel.isCurrentlySearchingAddress.asObservable(), viewModel.currentSelectedPlace.asObservable())
    .subscribe(onNext: { (isCurrentlySearchingAddress, currentSelectedPlace) in
    // Use isCurrentlySearchingAddress: Bool and currentSelectedPlace: GeocodePlace? here.
    if (isCurrentlySearchingAddress) {
        // TODO: 
    }
})
```

Also don't forget to add it to `DisposeBag`.